# Alert notifications and app inactive state in iOS 10

Tags: ios, ios10

In iOS 9, alert notifications are displayed in the center of the screen, and **move the current app to an inactive state**. They look like this:

[image]

In iOS 10, alert notifications are displayed in the top of the screen, and **do not move the current app to an inactive state** (`UIApplicationDelegate applicationWillResignActive` is not called). They look like this (essentially a banner notification which stays on screen):

[image]

The corresponding settings are for iOS 9:

[image]

The corresponding settings are for iOS 10:

[image]

I'm surprised that alert notification do not move the app to an inactive state any more in iOS 10. I was not able to find any mention of this change in the iOS 10 (developer) release notes. The corresponding Apple documentation about [Responding to Temporary Interruptions](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/StrategiesforHandlingAppStateTransitions/StrategiesforHandlingAppStateTransitions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH8-SW11) still states that:

> When an alert-based interruption occurs, such as an incoming phone call, the app moves temporarily to the inactive state so that the system can prompt the user about how to proceed.

Is this an intended change? Can I find documentation about it somewhere? Can anyone share experience with this change?

Comment: Probably the reason is in alert type: if it's modal dialog, the app becomes inactive, if it's banner - the app remains active.

Comment: @brigadir Yes, I think that is likely. Still, it's quite a big change not to be mentioned in any release notes.